# spring security permissions or roles based authorization on specific object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following scenario.

When a user logs in the application, he can create his own account. This will be the owner of one or more `object`s. Then he may create users for their `object`s so that each `object` may have a super admin, an administrator, a moderator and another kind of role/permissions.

Based on this description, I want each object to have some associated users which are having different roles and permissions.

How can I achieve this using spring security? Is there any other simpler way?

In my scenario, I think roles will be sufficient but I suppose in the future I will need permissions.

How can this be implemented?

I tried to design my database for this kind of scenario but the problem is how do I make it work with Spring and Spring Security.